# How to filter specific element of an array in wordpress/php?

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress

I have a php code as shown below in which I have added Line#A for the debugging purpose.

```
<div class="vidlist-main__meta cf">
    <?php

    //if ( has_excerpt() ) {the_excerpt();}
    $tags = get_the_tags( get_the_ID() );
    $cats = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() );                // Line#Z
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($cats); echo '</pre>';                  // Line#A
    if ( $tags || $cats  ) : ?>    // Line#B
        <span class="archive-links">
            <?php
            \CPAC\Episodes\generate_markup_for_categories( $cats );    // Line#C
            \CPAC\Episodes\generate_markup_for_tags( $tags );          // Line#D
            ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

On adding Line#A, I get the following o/p at different cases:

```
Case A:

Array
(
    [0] => 13085
    [1] => 13093
)

Case B:

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 13087
)

Case C:

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 13085
)
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what code I need to add after Line#Z or at Line#Z so that Line#Z takes only `[1]=>13093`.

Comment: The simplest thing is to use `array_diff` like this `$cats = array_diff($cats , [1])` then you can add more  `$cats = array_diff($cats , [1,2,3])`  etc. `$cats = array_diff(wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() ), [1]);`

Comment: if you really only want `so that Line#Z takes only [1]=>13093` then you can do the opposite with `array_intersect` Like this `$cats = array_intersect(wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() ), [13093]);`

Comment: I added this line `$cats = array_diff(wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() ), [13093]);` Now everything is showing excluding 13093.

Comment: yep that why I used `[1]` for *diff* and `[13093]` for *intersect*, not the other way around.  Diff is the difference of array1 from array2 or all the items in array1 not present in the other arrays, Intersect is the opposite.  All the items from array1 if they are present in any of the other arguments.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Can you explain me in an answer? comments are confusing me.

Comment: Yes but it's not clear you only want `13093`

Comment: I only want 13093 which can be at [0], [1] or [2] sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array intersect if you want to keep only one (or a few values)

```
<div class="vidlist-main__meta cf">
    <?php

    //if ( has_excerpt() ) {the_excerpt();}
    $tags = get_the_tags( get_the_ID() );
    $cats = array_intersect(wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() ), [13093]);                // Line#Z
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($cats); echo '</pre>';                  // Line#A
    if ( $tags || $cats  ) : ?>    // Line#B
        <span class="archive-links">
            <?php
            \CPAC\Episodes\generate_markup_for_categories( $cats );    // Line#C
            \CPAC\Episodes\generate_markup_for_tags( $tags );          // Line#D
            ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

The simplest example of this is:

```
$a = [13085,13093];
print_r(array_intersect($a, [13093]));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => 13093
)
```

[Sandox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55797d6a1a83a2c9370e6af3dd75e614021f1b76)